# Cannot create Cluster Manager instance( using Google Maps Android API Utility Library)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-utils

Update:(Problem solved)
FInally it is working in my **Intellij Idea 13**

The problem is that the library was not imported correctly.
Go  **Project Structure**, select **Modules**, add the library as module from an existing source,
then click it, it will show **Android** and check it as **Library Module**, then it would work

[image]
[image]

Im using `Google Maps Android API Utility Library` in my app. If i create a GoogleMap instance and move camera to specific location, it works! Code can be found below.

Unfortunately if I  invoke `mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, mMap);` and add items to it, the app will crash. Can anyone help? What is going on here?

```
public class MapActivity  extends  FragmentActivity{

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ClusterManager<MyItem> mClusterManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap != null) {
            return;
        }
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            //if comment out mCLusterManager instantiation, the app works and show the map 
            //mClusterManager = new ClusterManager<MyItem>(this, mMap);

           mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(51.5, -0.35), 9));
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the map.xml (got it from https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

Errors in logcat:

```
10-02 18:13:08.667    2854-2854/your.androidclient E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager
            at your.androidclient.AndroidClientActivity.setUpMapIfNeeded(AndroidClientActivity.java:115)
            at your.androidclient.AndroidClientActivity.onCreate(AndroidClientActivity.java:99)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: *the app will crash* - do you expect us to guess the exception?

Comment: im testing it on my phone, it only says "unfortunately app has stopped"  , I tried ` Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`  but didnt get anything

Comment: Did you check the logcat for the exception?

Comment: @Luksprog  sorry for my late reply, i was setting google maps working for my genymotion last 1 hour and i got the error in the logcat, please  see it in the question area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LogCat states

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.maps.android.clustering.ClusterManager`

This means that the maps-utils-library is not added to your final APK. Did you add it as a library (Project properties > Android > Library)?

Comment: im using intellij idea,  i already imported the library, but still not work

Comment: Hm, I'm working with Eclipse so unfortunately I cannot help you with IntelliJ. But as said above, the Exception means that the library is missing in the final APK.

Comment: thanks! +1 for you and I get it work with your help!

Answer (score 4):

The docs tell you to use:

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
```

Using this will give the error. You must use android-maps-utils:0.4.2

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4.2'
```

This will get rid of the error.

note: i posted in another answer to use 0.3+, although 0.4.2 is obviously better.  Either way, 0.4+ doesn't work and the others do

Comment: Thanks to seems to have solved it for me. Very strange fix! (I was also required to use exclude on the library that referred to the 0.4+ version)

Answer (score 2):

Edit your play services with bellow :

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}
```