# android - Google Maps. Set clustering distance for markers

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I'm using Google Maps Utils for clustering markers on my map.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering

It works fine, but I need to change clustering distance somehow because default distance is pretty huge:

[image: Here we can see 4 markers:]

[image]

On first picture we can see 5 markers (two of them are placed on each other). On the second picture I zoomed in just a little bit and all 5 markers were clustered in one. Is there any way to change clustering distance? They are clustering too early...

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27470137/6950238) question.

Comment: Andrii, no, there is just amount of clusters, not distance